# How to use password instead of key pairs ubuntu?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I started my amazon instance and i am using .ppk key to connect to my ssh, how can i disable that for now and use root access with just a password ?

Comment: Don't do it. Root password login is not secure.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+enable+password+login

Answer (score 2):

> Please try this way.

1. From an SSH client, log in to your EC2 instance.

> Use one of the following user names:
>
> > For Amazon Linux, the user name is ec2-user.
> >
> > For RHEL 5, the user name is either root or ec2-user.
> >
> > For Ubuntu, the user name is ubuntu.
> >
> > For SUSE Linux, the user name is either root or ec2-user.
> >
> > If ec2-user or root doesn't work, check with your AMI provider.

2. Set a password for user. The example below uses ec2-user as the user:

> > $ sudo passwd ec2-user
> >
> > Changing password for user ec2-user.
> >
> > New password:
> >
> > Retype new password:
> >
> > For example, a successful response looks like this:
> >
> > passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.

3. Update the PasswordAuthentication parameter in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:
   PasswordAuthentication yes
4. Restart the SSH service.

> > For Amazon Linux, RHEL 5, and SUSE Linux, use this command:
> >
> > sudo service sshd restart
> >
> > For Ubuntu, use this command:
> >
> > sudo service ssh restart

5. Exit the SSH client, and then log in to test the password authentication.